# Bucket documents into existing and non-existing field in Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bucket, elasticsearch-dsl

I am new to Elastic Search and am using the DSL to bucket my documents into two separate buckets:
those containing the field `extra_data.legend` and those that do not have that field at all.

Important to note is that `extra_data.legend` is a text field containing variable length paragraphs. So I am assuming a `terms` aggregation that buckets into unique values would be unpractical.

I have read about [Missing Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation), but the problem is that they are single-bucket aggregations. In my case, i would like to have two buckets, those that have the field and those that don't have it (i.e. does not exist in the document).

Is there an aggregation for the "complement" of Missing Aggregations, and can I combine both in a single result? or what would be the better way to approach this?